# Django Consecutive Days and Max Consecutive days Query

Tags: python, sql, django, postgresql, django-models

I have a following model.

```
class CategoryModel(BaseModel):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    icon = models.ImageField(upload_to=upload_icon_image_to)
    description = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    user = models.ForeignKey(User,on_delete=models.CasCade)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.name
```

The basic idea is that whenever a user added a category In one day whether being 1 or 20 records it is regarded as 1 streak and if the user again adds a new category then it is regarded as a +1 streak so current streak will be 2 and max streak is also 2 if user consecutively adds for 5 days streak is 5 days as it is max streak.

I just want to display as

```
{
"current_streak":3,
"max_streak":12
}
```

here current streak is 3 but previous streak set was 12 so it regarded as max streak
Any Idea how I can achieve this query?

Answer (score 2):

I would suggest a few things:

1. Overriding the `.save()` method or adding a `post_save` signal to `CategoryModel` so that you can process the streak logic.
2. Track when categories are created, this should be a simple `created_on` DateTime field.
3. Track the `current_streak` and `max_streak` on the User model

As for the implementation of tracking the streaks, something like this should work:

```py
from datetime import datetime, timedelta

class User
   ...

   def update_streak(self):
      """ 
      When a category is created, check whether a category was created 
      yesterday or not. If it was then add +1 to the streak, otherwise set 
      the streak to 1. Then check if the max streak has been bested.
      """
      today = datetime.now().date()
      yesterday = today - timedelta(days=1)

      # get the categories created yesterday to maintain the streak
      categories_created_yesterday = self.categorymodel_set.filter(
        created_on__gte=yesterday,
        created_on__lt=today
      )
   
      if categories_created_yesterday.exists():
          self.current_streak += 1
      else:
           self.current_streak = 1

      if self.current_streak > self.max_streak:
         self.max_streak = self.current_streak      

      self.save()
```

When a category has been created, you can call `category.user.update_streak()`

Comment: thanks I will implement and let you know  whether it works or not

Comment: actually this dont work

Comment: What doesn’t work about it?

Comment: if new data is made on next day max streak is not updated

Comment: Max streak won’t update until current streak is higher, does current streak get updated?